# ASUS UEFI BIOS Utility loop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have been having issues with my HDD for about 4 months now. Whenever I turn my PC on, it goes into ASUS UEFI BIOS Utility - EZ mode and it is a constant loop. No matter how many settings I’ve changed as recommended by professional, it never goes past this boot. However, when I use a different HDD the PC works fine. But this option isn’t the best as my available HDD is very slow and old, my PC is a gaming PC. Should I try downloading windows onto the old HDD through a USB, buy a new HDD, get it fixed by a professional, or any other suggestions you may have? Thank you.

Comment: They sell stand-alone devices that will let you clone an HDD to another HDD, and your issue suggests the HDD might be failing.  It's trivial to download a WIndows 10 ISO.